# How to increase parquet file size inserted with impala?

Tags: insert, avro, impala

Impala statement
INSERT INTO  PARTITION(...) SELECT * FROM 
creates many ~350 MB parquet files in every partition.

"Parquet data files use a 1GB block size, so when deciding how finely to partition the data, try to find a granularity where each partition contains 1GB or more of data, rather than creating a large number of smaller files split among many partitions."

I use impala version 1.1.1.

How to increase parquet file size?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your query? How are you partitioning the data?

Comment: INSERT INTO tblParquet PARTITION(year,month,day,hour) SELECT * FROM  tblAvro WHERE year='2013' AND month='09' AND day='05'. Both, Avro and Parquet tables partitoned year/month/day/hour and have the same structure.

Comment: and the table created with
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblParquet(<...>, createDate BIGINT, <...>) 
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string, hour string) 
STORED AS PARQUETFILE LOCATION '<tableLocation>'

Comment: Input for my test is 250GB of gz compressed files (24 hours of events). After the "Impala Insert" with [year,month,day,hour] partitioning, each hourly partition includes 5-10 ~350 MB snappy compressed files (1GB hdfs block size). 

In another test with [year,month,day] partitioning, the number of created files was around 300(!), with ~350 MB size each.